# How to add a URL item to Outlook mail folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, url

In Outlook 2010, I drag a url from Chrome addressbar into an email folder.

It seems to work fine, in the Outlook email folder, the url's title is shown and the icon is a globe (url reference).

Problem: When I click on the entry in the folder, I get the error message:

> Cannot open this item. Outlook blocked access to this potentially unsafe item.

**Is there a way to have Outlook open/display the url in the default browser?**

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to unblock the item (see below). However, now Outlook says that the item (url reference) needs to be saved to the desktop before it can be opened. That works, but is not convenient. Instead, I'll just send an email to myself with the url in it.

To unblock one or more attachment types, follow [MS procedure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829982)

[List of file types that are blocked by default](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/blocked-attachments-in-outlook-HA001229952.aspx) -- includes .url filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

to bypass the file save dialog as well, specifically for Outlook 2016 (and probably above) ...

the first registry entry as mentioned by @larry-k is required:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security

Level1Remove REG_SZ .url
```

then to bypass the file save dialog:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security
╔════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════╗
║            Name            ║   Type    ║      Data      ║
╠════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║ adminsecuritymode          ║ REG_DWORD ║ 0x00000003 (3) ║
║ fileextensionsremovelevel1 ║ REG_SZ    ║ .url           ║
║ fileextensionsremovelevel2 ║ REG_SZ    ║ .url           ║
╚════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════╝
```

at this point, the first time you attempt to open a .url item in outlook you will be prompted by an "are you sure?" popup with a "do not ask again" checkbox that **will be disabled**... i found that we can enable these kinds of checkboxes by launching outlook in "administrative" mode by holding down CTRL+SHIFT while clicking on the outlook app icon... note: you must then restart outlook WITHOUT admin mode to be able to drag and drop web links into outlook entries again (if you see the red circle with line mouse icon during your drag-drop, it is because you are in this admin mode).

fyi, i still receive a popup dialog "File Download - Security Warning - Do you want to open this file? OPEN CANCEL"... i don't know if that can be avoided yet but at least we don't have to stumble through saving a file just to view the web pages links we'd like to store in outlook.

the above entries correspond to local group policy settings (i.e. gpedit.msc) at this path:
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Outlook 2016 > Security > Security Form Settings and > Attachment Security

if interested in the group policy approach versus direct registry entries, one must load these administrative templates by downloading them from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) and  saving them to `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions`. If that link goes stale, search for "Administrative Template files (ADMX/ADML) and Office Customization Tool for Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise, Office 2019, and Office 2016".

here is the documentation for each setting above copied from the group policy templates:

**adminsecuritymode**

This policy setting controls which set of security settings are enforced in Outlook.

If you enable this policy setting, you can choose from four options for enforcing Outlook security settings:

- (0) Outlook Default Security - This option is the default configuration in Outlook. Users can configure security themselves, and Outlook ignores any security-related settings configured in Group Policy.
- (1) Use Security Form from 'Outlook Security Settings' Public Folder - Outlook uses the settings from the security form published in the designated public folder.
- (2) Use Security Form from 'Outlook 10 Security Settings' Public Folder - Outlook uses the settings from the security form published in the designated public folder.
- (3) Use Outlook Security Group Policy - Outlook uses security settings from Group Policy.

Important -  You must enable this policy setting if you want to apply the other Outlook security policy settings mentioned in this guide.

**fileextensionsremovelevel1**

This policy setting controls which types of attachments (determined by file extension) Outlook prevents from being delivered.

Outlook uses two levels of security to restrict user's access to files attached to e-mail messages or other items. Files with specific extensions can be categorized as Level 1 (users cannot view the file) or Level 2 (users can open the file after saving it to disk). Users can freely open files of types that are not categorized as Level 1 or Level 2.

**fileextensionsremovelevel2**

This policy setting controls which types of attachments (determined by file extension) must be saved to disk before users can open them.